# Check regex pattern with table value using php

Tags: php, sql, regex

I have an SQL table:

```
date
************************
|  id   |  date format |
************************
|   1   | 2013-02-10   |
|   2   | 02-02-2013   |
|   3   | 20130202     |
************************
```

I want to store the diff (date format) in the date table, checking with the following pattern against the table date:

```
/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/
```

How can I check this pattern against the `date format` field in the date table?

Comment: you can use `REGEXP` in mysql

Comment: Firstly, don't go calling your tables things closely resembling reserved words like "date".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you stored date like that.

I'm assuming your database is MySQL, if it is you could use [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function as follows:

```
select `date format` from mytable where str_to_date(`date format`, '%d-%m-%Y') is not null;
```

Note that this query is not going to be efficient as it has to scan every row and apply the `str_to_date` function.

Comment: i don't know why you didn't use `REGEXP`

Comment: i want to check regex pattern its not fix only date check like time date-time string etc...

Comment: @user2496644, Please see the linked documentation.  This function returns `DATETIME`.  However, if you specifically want to use regex then DevZer0's answer should do it for you.

Comment: solve i fix it... :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309094/check-regex-pattern-with-table-value-using-php/18310600#18310600

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Through this syntax you can check its **regex** pattern

```
  int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your regexp with slight modification to a query it self.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date format` REGEXP '^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$'
```

Comment: its work but my pattern is not valid on work /^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/

Comment: your pattern includes `\d` qualifier which is not recognized in mysql

Comment: but i have lost of pattern this type so what i can do... ? for solve

Comment: replace `\d` with `[0-9]`

Comment: i fix it... :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309094/check-regex-pattern-with-table-value-using-php/18310600#18310600

Answer (score 0):

i fix it... (y)

```
<?php
$pattern = '/^\d{4}$/';
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!mysql_select_db('regex_field')) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query('SELECT date_format FROM date');

$date = array();
$newdate = array();

while ($date_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $date[] = $date_row;
}

foreach($date AS $key => $value) {
    $newdate[$key] = $value['date_format'];
}

foreach($newdate as $key => $value) {
    $testexample = @preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches);

    if($testexample == true) {
        echo "Example & Pattern Match";

        exit;
    }
}

echo "Example & Pattern MisMatch";

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: don't use the `@` sign. [read this](http://themessycode.blogspot.com/2013/08/cost-of-error-suppression-and-ignorance.html)

Comment: In addition to DevZer0's comment, `mysql_` functions are deprecated, please start looking into `mysqli` or `PDO`.